# Can multi-environment configuration be used in 'index.php'?

Tags: multi-environment

On my local dev sever, as well as the production server, the `craft` folder is one level above web root, so `$craftPath` in `index.php` is set like so:

`$craftPath = '../craft';`

On the staging server, the `craft` folder is two levels above web root, so `$craftPath` needs to be:

`$craftPath = '../../craft';`

Can this be accomplished in a single index.php file? Something similar to the multi-environment array in `config/general.php` and `config/db.php` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be able to. Use a switch statement to check on the host and then server up the correct environment configuration like so:

public/index.php:

```
switch (strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
{
    // Staging
    case 'stage.mydomain.com' :
        define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'stage');
        $craftPath = '../../craft';
        break;

    // Local
    default :
        define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'local');
        $craftPath = '../craft';
        break;
}
```